# Trying to display an array part after part

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently displaying the content of an array in a view, let say `$scope.array`.

I load the content of an array with a request to my serv. 
Sadly `$scope.array` contains a lot of elements an displaying every elements at once in the view takes a while.

In order to enhance user experience, I'd like to display the array part by part. At first I thought that `$scope` was able to handle it if I just proceed to add data chunk by chunk to `$scope.array`, but nope.

I figured out that the current `$digest` loop would only be over when my array was full. I tried with Async lib to add chunks asynchronously to `$scope` hoping for a way to dodge the `$digest` issue, but it doesn't work.

Now I kinda ran out of ideas to display datas properly, so if you had any experience with this kind of issues I'd be glad to hear about it !

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nobody will ever spend their time reading a table with 20k rows anyway, problem solved :)

Comment: Pagination ? Try that. Show a part of your array and add buttons to see the rest.

Comment: Well, it's more like 500 rows, and my user asks for it specifically :/

Plus i'm displaying datas by months/year, so there already is a browsing feature on the list, adding a pagination seems weird to me from user pov.

Comment: The performance problem here comes from the 2-way data binding. That's a lot of rows, and Angular is watching all these lines for changes. You need one-way data binding (just display, without watch), that'll be much faster.

Comment: User also want to edit data from the list ... :/ 
Only one or two buttons but still

Comment: Pagination seems the obvious choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pagination, periodic requests etc is ruled out then...

You can have all of your data in one array not bound to ui. 
You then periodically add the data into a second array that is bound to the ui. Similar to how you mentioned you are already doing it but simply add the chunks in a $timeout or an $interval. This lets the $digests and page renders complete.

Simple Example:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in shownItems track by $index">
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  //array that is bound to ui
  $scope.shownItems = [];
  //backing data 
  var fullItemsList = [];
  //Create some fake data, you wouldn't do this in your program,
  // this is where you would fetch from server
  for(var ii = 0; ii < 50000; ii++){
    fullItemsList.push("AYYYLMAO "  + ii);
  }

  //How many items to add at a time
  var chunkSize = 500;
  //keep track of how many we have already added
  var currentChunkIndex = 0;

  //transfers a chunk of items to ui-bound array 
  function addMoreItems(){
    var start = currentChunkIndex * chunkSize;
    var end = (currentChunkIndex + 1) * chunkSize;
    for(var ii = start; ii < end; ii++){
      if(!fullItemsList[ii]){
        break;
      }
      $scope.shownItems.push(fullItemsList[ii]);
    }
    currentChunkIndex++;
  }

  //Transfer chunk of items in a timeout, trigger another timeout to 
  //add more if there are stil items to transfer
  function periodicAdd(){
    $timeout(function(){
      addMoreItems();
      if(currentChunkIndex*chunkSize >= $scope.shownItems.length){
        periodicAdd();
      }
    },0);
  }
  //Add the first chunk straight away, otherwise it will wait for the 
  //first timeout.
  addMoreItems();
  //Start the timeout periodic add.
  periodicAdd();
}]);
```

[Example plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RJK3s3uXkcvQ5rlrv3rG?p=preview)

Keep in mind that this example is very rough. For instance the initial "load" of 50k rows will run on ui thread whereas your data load will presumably come async from your server. This also means you need to kick off the periodic adding only when your request completes. So yeah just a rough example.

Note that I use a 0 millisecond timeout.This will still push the callback to the end of the current processing queue, it wont execute straight away despite being 0 milliseconds. You might want to increase it a little bit to give your app a bit of breathing room. Remember to properly dispose of timeouts.

Comment: Thank you ! It is exactly what I tried to do. I wasn't aware of the $timeout behavior, good to know

Comment: I've encountered an issue trying to do it with $timeout : It seems like $timeout is called at the function initialization and starts the loop before my request even end. 

I fixed it using $interval, maybe I misunderstood what was going on but it works fine like this.

Comment: Yes in my answer I did say that my example started the loading straight away and in your code you should start it only after your data loads

Answer (score 0):

Use server side pagination. Even using one-time bindings is not always the solution, especially if there is complex template logic (show/hide parts depending on the data properties) and if the editing is required.

If you want to filter your array by some criteria (for example, month and year), implement this on the backend and pass your criteria to the server: `GET /my_data?year=2017&month=7&page=1`.